# How to get 'this' value using onclick inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code here:

```
<div class="row">
            <p align="center" class="panel-body alert-info">* It is important to enter student data first rather than book</p>
            <form action="addbooks.php" method="post">

            <p align="center" class="panel-body alert-info">Choose the add type: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="bauthor" name="book" value="bauthor" onclick="booksclicked(this);">&nbsp;Author/Student&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="books" name="book" value="books" onclick="booksclicked(this);">&nbsp;Thesis&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="ref_books" name="book" value="ref_books" onclick="booksclicked(this);">&nbsp;References Books</p>

            <script>
            function booksclicked(){
                if (document.getElementById('bauthor').checked) {
                    //var ques1 = document.getElementById("dem").innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById("demu").innerHTML = "<p align='center'>*Fill the form(STUDENT)</p>"+
                    "<p><u>STUDENT FORM</u></p><br>"+
                    "<p>Student Matric Number"+
                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='addmatricno' id='addmatricno' placeholder='Enter student matric number' size='20px'><br><br>"+
                    "Student Name"+
                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='addname' id='addname' placeholder='Enter student name'><br><br>"+
                    "Student Programme"+
                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='addprogramme' id='addprogramme' placeholder='Enter student programme'><br><br>"+
                    "Student Education Level"+
                    "<select name='selectedulevel' id='selectedulevel' class='form-control'>"+
                    "<option selected disabled>Select education level</option>"+
                    "<option value='PHD'>PHD</option>"+
                    "<option value='MASTER'>MASTER</option>"+
                    "<option value='DEGREE'>DEGREE</option></p></select><br><br>"+
                    "<p align='center'><input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='submitaddstudent' id='submitaddstudent' value='Add Student' style = 'width:'20%; text-align: center;' onclick='return saddstudent(this.id)'></p><br><br>";
                }

                <div id="demu" class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-xs md-12 col-sm-12 text-left panel-body alert-info"></div>
```

As you can see on the last line of code here is my submit button where i put the onclick code.

Then on my javascript i have like this

```
 function saddstudent(a){
        alert("fds");
        return false;
        /*  if(!a.addmatricno.value || !a.addname.value || !a.addprogramme.value || !a.selectedulevel.value){
                alert("PLease complete the student form");
                return false;
            }*/
}
```

Its not only about the data has not been passed, but when clicked, its not even go to this function. That is weird. Is it because im using innerHTML? or is it something i missed here

Comment: What errors do you get in the web console?

Comment: No error. Its just wont alert anything. I put alert in the function to check if it go to this function when clicked

Comment: If you want to only add parts of your code you should edit it in a way that it is still complete. This is kind of messy, where does your div even end? Or booksclicked() function for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no element with `id="demu"` and Closing curly brace `{` of If and `booksclicked()` function were missing

```js
function saddstudent(a){
        alert("fds");
        return false;
}
function booksclicked(){
                if (document.getElementById('bauthor').checked) {
                    //var ques1 = document.getElementById("dem").innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById("demu").innerHTML = "<p align='center'>*Fill the form(STUDENT)</p>"+
    "<p><u>STUDENT FORM</u></p><br>"+
    "<p>Student Matric Number"+
    "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='addmatricno' id='addmatricno' placeholder='Enter student matric number' size='20px'><br><br>"+
    "Student Name"+
    "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='addname' id='addname' placeholder='Enter student name'><br><br>"+
    "Student Programme"+
    "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='addprogramme' id='addprogramme' placeholder='Enter student programme'><br><br>"+
    "Student Education Level"+
    "<select name='selectedulevel' id='selectedulevel' class='form-control'>"+
    "<option selected disabled>Select education level</option>"+
    "<option value='PHD'>PHD</option>"+
    "<option value='MASTER'>MASTER</option>"+
    "<option value='DEGREE'>DEGREE</option></p></select><br><br>"+
    "<p align='center'><input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='submitaddstudent' id='submitaddstudent' value='Add Student' style = 'width:'20%; text-align: center;' onclick='return saddstudent(this)'></p><br><br>";
                  }
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <p align="center" class="panel-body alert-info">* It is important to enter student data first rather than book</p>
            <form action="addbooks.php" method="post">

            <p align="center" class="panel-body alert-info">Choose the add type: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="bauthor" name="book" value="bauthor" onclick="booksclicked(this);">&nbsp;Author/Student&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="books" name="book" value="books" onclick="booksclicked(this);">&nbsp;Thesis&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" id="ref_books" name="book" value="ref_books" onclick="booksclicked(this);">&nbsp;References Books</p>
<div id="demu"></div>
```

Comment: that is weird. i wonder how you can make it success.. Let me try it first

Comment: Thanks a lot. Based on your code i just realized that i have problem on my javascript code placement for that alert. Before this i put my javascript code just after the php code where it execute the form to insert data to the database. When i put my javascript on top of that, it goes well and also it worked when i put just before the php code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use `onclick="return saddstudent(this);"`, the value of the argument you receive will be a reference to the element that click was on — in your case, the `input type="submit"`. But your code seems to expect it to be the form.

The minimal change is to use `onsubmit="return saddstudent(this);"` on the `form` element instead.

> Its not only about the data has not been passed, but when clicked, its not even go to this function.

You have to declare `saddstudent` at global scope in order to be able to use it from an attribute-style event handler. You haven't shown where you declare it, but if the function's not getting called at all, it sounds like it's not defined in global scope.

---

The larger change is to keep your domains separate: JavaScript in JavaScript files, HTML in HTML files, and to use modern event handling techniques.